# How to wait until appended html has loaded assets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery plugin that generates HTML. I need to somehow wait until the appended html has finished loading it's assets to append it again. I tried window.load but that didn't work. The only thing working that will modify the the targeted area is a setTimeout callback which I feel is very hacky.

How can I accomplish what I am trying to do? 
The current code I am trying to run on the generated markup is:

```
jQuery('ol').append('<li data-toggle="modal" id="thumb" class="yt-thumb" overflow-scroll="false" overflow-scroll="true" data-target="#youtubeModal"><img src="/images/dome-thumb.jpg" /></li> '); // add youtube to thumb slider
 jQuery('ol').appendTo( jQuery('#thumb-area') )
```

Comment: Assets as in images? or assets as in DOM nodes? DOM nodes are appended synchronously. Images just require an onload handler.

Comment: More specifically, I'm trying to figure out why I can't append an area that is generated by a plugin unless a setimeout with 1200 ms is called. I just need away for that code above to work without a set timeout

Comment: You need to update your question to be more clear and include a [mcve], without that as a minimum, this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic), and should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what I would do, I recognize its not perfect but you could insert the image into the dom sepratly with an onload event and when that is called back insert the modal knowing that the browser has completely loaded the image.

```
$('body').append('<img style="display:none" id="temp">');
$tempImg = $('img#temp');
$tempImg.on('load', function() {
     // Append your modal here
     jQuery('ol').append('<li data-toggle="modal" id="thumb" class="yt-thumb" overflow-scroll="false" overflow-scroll="true" data-target="#youtubeModal"><img src="/images/dome-thumb.jpg" /></li> '); // add youtube to thumb slider
     jQuery('ol').appendTo( jQuery('#thumb-area'))
});
$tempImg.attr('src', '/images/dome-thumb.jpg');
```

So when you update the src on the hidden temp image the browser will download the image, then when that is finished you insert the modal.